# Abstract Factory for Template Class Dilemma

Tags: c++, templates, abstract-factory

**Overview**

The technical problem is the current design appears to require an abstract factory for a C++ template worker class, which as far as I can see, is not possible. Thus, I need an alternative solution to prevent clients from depending on the worker's implementation details and the worker from any specific client environment.

**The Setting**

I have a `Worker` class that internally requires a container class `C` to memorize processing information. The processing information is organized in a `BufferType` struct, so `Worker` internally deals with a member of type `C< BufferType >`. On the other hand, we don't want the `Worker`'s clients to know about `Worker::BufferType`, which reflect API-irrelevant implementation details of `Worker` that may change over time.

The situation is complicated by the fact that `C` is an abstract class that has different implementations of the container functionality depending on the actual environment (e.g. a database). Obviously, we don't want `Worker` to know about that, it shall work in any environment for which there is an implementation of `C`.

Since I don't have that much experience in writing factories I went ahead and wrote the following:

These are the containers I have to deal with:

```
template <class T>
class C {
    // container interface
};

template <class T>
class CImpl : public C<T> {
    // implements C's interface
};
```

This is how I would have liked to implement the `Worker` class:

```
class Worker {
public:
    Worker( AbstractCFactory& f ) : _f( &f ), _buffer( NULL ) {}    
    void doSomething() {
        _buffer = _f->create<BufferType>( );
        // ... do something with _buffer
    }
private:
    AbstractCFactory* _f;
    typedef struct { int someInfo; } BufferType;
    C< BufferType >* _buffer;    
};
```

However, this would require something like the following in terms of factories:

```
class AbstractCFactory {
public:
    template <class T>
    virtual C< T >* create() = 0; 
};

class ConcreteCFactory : public AbstractCFactory {
public:
    template <class T>
    virtual C< T >* create() {
        return new CImpl< T >(); 
    }
};
```

While I thought this was a great design, the compiler was not quite so enthusiastic and reminded me that template methods cannot be virtual. Now that I think about it, this makes sense - the compiler cannot know which code to generate for the template method in the factory if the factory type is only determined during runtime.

**The Ugly Workaround**

First, I implemented the factories as templates to allow a virtual `create()` function:

```
template <class T>
class AbstractCFactory {
public:     
    virtual C< T >* create() = 0;
};

template <class T>
class ConcreteCFactory : public AbstractCFactory {
public:
    virtual C< T >* create() {
        return new CImpl< T >(); 
    }
};
```

Then, I moved the `BufferType` to the public interface of `Worker`, allowing the client to create a `ConcreteCFactory< Worker::BufferType >` instance to be passed to `Worker`'s constructor.

```
class Worker {
public:
    typedef struct { int someInfo; } BufferType; 
    Worker( AbstractCFactory< BufferType >& f ) : _f( &f ), _buffer( NULL ) {}    
    void doSomething() {
        _buffer = _f->create( );
        // ... do something with _buffer
    }
private:
    AbstractCFactory< BufferType >* _f;
    C< BufferType >* _buffer;    
};
```

Obviously, my workaround is not a real solution, because it still introduces an undesirable client dependency on private implementation details of `Worker` (`BufferType`) by exposing them to the public interface.

**Question**

Is there a proper solution that does not force me to break encapsulation, i.e. keep the `Worker` independent from `CImpl` and the client independent from `Worker::BufferType`?

Comment: I think that there are some possible solutions. But I do not clearly understand what will be the public interface of your system. Should the declaration of BufferType be in the public .h declaring the Worker class ?

Comment: No, it should not, since it represents a data structure used only internally by `Worker` that should not be exposed to the public API. In my 'ugly workaround' I had to move it there for the client to be able to generate the correctly specialized `CImpl`, but that is exactly the reason why I used the word 'ugly' there.

Answer (score 1):

`CImpl<T>` is a template class that must to be provided by client, and it must be specialized in a `CImpl<BufferType>`. At specialization time, both `CImpl` and `BufferType` must be defined. One possibility would be to ask the client to provide a `CImpl.h` file containing the definition of a implementation of `C<T>`:

cimpl.h (provided by client)

```
template <class T>
class CImpl : public C<T> {
    // implements C's interface
};
```

worker.h:

```
class IC {
};

template <class T>
class C: public IC {
    // container interface
};

class AbstractCFactory {
public:     
    virtual IC* create() = 0;
};

class Worker {
public:
    Worker( AbstractCFactory& f ) : _f( &f ), _buffer( 0 ) {}    
    void doSomething();
private:
    AbstractCFactory* _f;
    C< struct BufferType >* _buffer;    
};  

AbstractCFactory& getDefaultFactory();
```

worker.cpp

```
#include "worker.h"
#include "cimpl.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

template <class T>
class ConcreteCFactory : public AbstractCFactory {
public:
    virtual IC* create() {
        return new CImpl< T >(); 
    }
};

struct BufferType {
    int someInfo;
};

void Worker::doSomething() {
    _buffer = static_cast<C<BufferType>*>(_f->create( ));
    // ... do something with _buffer
}

AbstractCFactory& getDefaultFactory() {
    static ConcreteCFactory<BufferType> f;

    return f;
}
```

Example of usage:

```
#include "worker.h"
...
AbstractCFactory& f = getDefaultFactory();
Worker w(f);
w.doSomething();
```

---

Another possibility is to split the .h file in 2 pieces, one *public* interface and one *private* one that client should never use directly.

worker.h

```
class IC {
};

template <class T>
class C: public IC {
    // container interface
};

class AbstractCFactory {
public:     
    virtual IC* create() = 0;
};

struct BufferType;

class Worker {
public:
    Worker( AbstractCFactory& f ) : _f( &f ), _buffer( 0 ) {}    
    void doSomething();
private:
    AbstractCFactory* _f;
    C< struct BufferType >* _buffer;    
};  

AbstractCFactory& getFactory();

#include "private.h"
```

private.h:

```
struct BufferType {
    int someInfo;
};

template<class I> 
class CFactory: public AbstractCFactory {
public:
    virtual IC* create() {
        return new I(); 
    }
};

template<class I>
AbstractCFactory& getFactory() {
    static CFactory<I> fact;

    return fact;
}
```

worker.cpp:

```
#include "worker.h"

void Worker::doSomething() {
    _buffer = static_cast<C<BufferType>*>(_f->create( ));
    // ... do something with _buffer
}
```

Example of usage:

```
#include "worker.h"
...
template <class T>
class CImpl : public C<T> {
    // implements C's interface
};
...
AbstractCFactory& f = getFactory<CImpl<BufferType>>();
Worker w(f);
w.doSomething();
```

Comment: Ok, so Worker and C and in public interface, BufferType is a private implementation, and CImpl is only known by client. I had not understood that last part and I should propose something in a while taking it into account.`

Comment: @ExternalCompilerError: Post edited with 2 implementations using a CImpl provided by client.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed suggestions! For proposal one (client-provided `cimpl.h`) the client code looks exactly like it should. Also, the client does not depend on `BufferType`, we can update the worker without having to recompile or redeploy the client. However, having `worker.cpp` include `cimpl.h` requires to build different versions of the worker, one for each environment, and I would have multiple different versions of `cimpl.h` and compiled workers flying around, one for each environment.

Comment: The second proposal, while it has the advantage that it more explicitly states which part of the `Worker` API is truly public, it apparently suffers from a similar drawback of my 'ugly workaround', namely that `BufferType` is exposed, requiring the client to explicitly use it during factory instantiation.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I doubt that my idea of an optimal solution, where client and `Worker` are two separately deployable components and `Worker` does not depend on `CImpl` and the client not on `BufferType`, is possible with a `Worker` using `C<BufferType>`. Your proposals triggered the following thought, though: If I did not use `BufferType` directly for the container items, but changed `Worker` to use a `C<shared_ptr<BufferType>>`, it should be possible for the client to create a typed factory without knowing `BufferType`'s size.

Comment: @ExternalCompilerError: It would certainly be better than the client provided class `CImpl` do not depend on the internal class `BufferType`. My proposal are only workarounds, and none is a clear and neat solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes overusing patterns is not good . If you don't want client to know about you `BufferType` you should use a template specialization in your `CImpl` with `BufferType` and build your worker without factory pattern.

Comment: If I understand your suggestion correctly, this would mean that I do the specialization of `CImpl` within the `Worker` class. And if it would be ok for the `Worker` to depend on `CImpl`, I would agree with you, and the abstract factory would indeed be a case of pattern overuse. However, `CImpl` implements `C` for a certain environment, thus introducing new dependencies that `Worker` is not allowed to have. Worker must only know about the abstract interface `C`.

Comment: template <typename T>
class C
{
private:
 T x;
};

class CImpl :public  C<int>
{

}; this is what I meant by my answer worker will not be impacted by the template

Comment: Right, but I would need to make it `class CImpl : public C<BufferType>`, but there ought to be no single source file in which both `CImpl` and `BufferType` are known (only the client knows about `CImpl`, and only the `Worker` about `BufferType`).